# Insert rows into a join table directly in JPA / JPQL?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way in JPA to insert rows directly into a join table?  I have the following Contract and Attachment entities:

```
public class Contract implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    private String number;
    private String volume;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "contract_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "attachment_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Attachment> attachments;
}
```

`Attachment` entity:

```
public class Attachment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    private String name;
}
```

Due to thread concurrency issues, I would like to add attachments to the contract directly without needing to load the contract, add the Attachment to the list and persist/save the Contract, since there is not data being updated in the Contract object itself.  To be a little more verbose, I have multiple threads in parallel saving attachments, and if I were to persist the Contract in all those threads, I would need to put in some kind of concurrency control to avoid OptimisticLockExceptions.  Given that the Contract entity is not being modified (only the join table is), I do not want to put in a bottleneck and only update the join table directly.

Is there a way in JPA and/or JPQL to insert rows directly into the join table?  Workflow would be to persist the Attachment, and then insert the appropriate row into the join table.

Is there a way to retrieve the JPA-generated join-table name from the entity?

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `contract` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `attachment` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=197 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `contract_attachment` (
  `contract_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `attachment_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_27094bpt88d7bfngq5v52jrs` (`attachment_id`),
  KEY `FK_i1ycj6ewd536bky08t0jjh15d` (`contract_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_i1ycj6ewd536bky08t0jjh15d` FOREIGN KEY (`contract_id`) REFERENCES `contract` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_27094bpt88d7bfngq5v52jrs` FOREIGN KEY (`attachment_id`) REFERENCES `attachment` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: you can of course persist just an `Attachment`, but due to Data-pooling and caching this information probably would not be visible to you program until restarting it i.e. the same as if you inserted a record directly into the DB using another client.

Comment: @ScaryWombat - Hence the need/reason to use JPQL (via the Entity Manager) to update the join table.

Comment: after doing the `Attachment` inserts call `entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll()` to flush you caches.

Comment: @ScaryWombat But the problem is that I have to persist the Contract object, otherwise the join table won't be updated.  But if I persist the Contract object, it will update its version (even though nothing in the Contract table itself is changed) and consequently another thread will get an OptimisticLockException since the version numbers no longer match.  Which is why I'm looking for a way to just update the join table without modifying the contract table.

Comment: As there is nothing in the `Contract` table that actually needs updating, and if the data is **not cached** then if a `Attachment` is linked to the `Attachment`, a new read of the data should return all rows.  Assuming the data model is one-many rather than one-link table-one

Comment: @ScaryWombat Sorry - I'm not able to follow you "if an `Attachment is linked to the `Attachment`".  I'm not sure what you mean.  The goal, of course, is after all the Attachments are persisted, that I can do a new Contract.findById(contractId).getAttachments() and have the full list.  The only way that would work is by updating the join table, but no idea how to do that (without persisting the Contract object which I am looking to avoid).

Comment: maybe it would be helpful to know what your DB schema is really like.  Is there a real link table?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I updated the question to include the DDL.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you need to add cascade property to @ManyToMany annotation. Use PERSIST or ALL.
But it is really not clear description, you say that you do not want to load Contract, but how you are going to persist/save Contract without loading?

If you really do not want to load contract and just persist Attachment, you need to add @ManyToMany relation to your Attachment. And then add contract (you still need to load it, but you do not need to have it up-to-date). It should be something like that:

```java
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "attachment_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "contract_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Contract> contracts;
```

Comment: I have several threads persisting attachments in parallel. Consequently, I cannot load/persist the Contract entity or will run into OptimisticLockExceptions.  Given that there is no actual data being updated in the Contract object (and only in the join table), I'm looking to update the join table directly.  Putting the relation in the Attachment object does not work either, as Attachment is "entity-agnostic" - meaning that it is reused in several different entities (similar to Contract) and putting the relation in Attachment kind of makes Attachment knowledgable about it's "parent" ...

Comment: ... hence the need/desire to be able to access the join table directly.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a good strategy to have "entity-agnostic", you should only use JPA enities on Persistence Tier, so I think it is ok to add second-side relation and have contracts, and other entities. They will be lazily loaded. In stricter case you can accessors protected.
From my experience you do not need to update two-sides of mapping, if you will have Contract not up-to-date, then add this contract to Attachment and persist Attachment everything will work OK. Ofcouse after that Contract is not up-to-date object.